# How to fetch postgres table in parallel using python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a table named "order_lines" since it is has almost 7 million rows it takes me around 30 minutes to pull it and dump into a csv. I was hoping if I can pull it in parallel so as to reduce load time using python. My end objective is to replicate it in redshift.

Can someone please suggests methods to pull this table in python ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you can use potgresql `\copy my_table to 'filename' csv header` for exporting your table data to csv file

Comment: Tip: https://github.com/Clever/postgres-to-redshift

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query with admin privilege :

```
COPY (select col1,col2 from your_table) TO 'some_file_location/filename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

OR on your command prompt of server :

```
psql -U user -d db_name -c "Copy (Select * From your_table) To STDOUT With CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';" > filename_data.csv
```

Comment: I want to pull this table in parallel for example if I have data for 24 months I would like to create 24 different processes to pull data simultaneously and merge them  in a csv

Comment: i suggest in your select query get month wise data and copy to csv file and use csv merge from pyhton.